# recursive function help/explanation

Tags: python, function, recursion

Can someone explain what happens after lower is greater than upper and 0 is returned? I can not wrap my head around how the program is producing `4,7,9,10`. I believe 0 is returned from the iteration of the call to ourSum() within the ourSum() function. This would set results to 1 + 0 which would equal to 1. Can someone spare a few moments to walk me through this?

```
def ourSum(lower, upper, margin=0):
    blanks = ' ' * margin
    print(blanks, lower, upper)
    if lower > upper:
        print(blanks, 0)
        return 0
    else:
        results = lower + ourSum(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)
        print(blanks, results)
        return results
```

Results from `ourSum(1,4)` below:

```
 1 4
     2 4
         3 4
             4 4
                 5 4
                 0
             4
         7
     9
 10
10
```

Comment: Try changing `print(blanks, results)` to `print(blanks, lower, oursum_result, results)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ourSum(1, 4):

- this prints ' 1 4'
- then checks: 1 < 4 -> False
- so results = 1 + ourSum(2, 4, 4)
  this keeps happening until lower > upper, which happens at 5 > 4.  But at this point we have 4 levels of recursion which still need numerical result returned:
- ourSum(1, 4, 0), ourSum(2, 4, 4), ourSum(3, 4, 8), ourSum(4, 4, 12)

So first ourSum(5, 4, 16) returns 0 due to:

```
    if lower > upper:
    print(blanks, 0)
    return 0
```

- ourSum(5, 4, 16) returns 0 so the previous recursion gets --> results = 4 (lower was = 4 at this point) + 0.  So we print 4 with the appropriate number of 'blanks', AND we return results (which = 4)
- The previous recursion was sitting there with:

  results = 3 + ourSum(4, 4, 12)
  but we just returned the result of ourSum(4, 4, 12) which was = 4.

So now:

- results = 3 + 4 = 7.  Print 7 and blanks and return results (ourSum(3, 4, 8) returns 7)

Keep doing this with results = 2 + ourSum(3, 4, 8), but this is 7 so results = 9.  Print and keep going for the remaining results = 1 + ourSum(2, 4, 4) = 10 and finally, for our initial problem of ourSum(1, 4) we return results = 10.

Comment: when you say `"The previous recursion was sitting there with"`, is this a  queue of ourSum()'s waiting for the current function to return `results`? i think this is what was confusing me...

Comment: python is pushing each function call (each ourSum(a, b, c)) onto a stack.  So the bottom of the stack (as far as we are interested in) would hold ourSum(1, 4, 0), followed by ourSum(2, 4, 4) and so on.  Here is a great recursion tutorial in python http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/recursionsimple.html.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough illustration of what's happening:
Let's forget about `print` and `margin` for now.

- First we have `ourSum(1,4)`

  - `else` clause takes place : it returns  `1 + ourSum(2,4)`

    - Another `else`, `ourSum(2,4)` returns `2 + ourSum(3,4)`

      - `ourSum(3,4)` returns `3 + ourSum(4,4)`

        - `ourSum(4,4)` returns `4+ourSum(5,4)`

          - Finally the `if`. `return ourSum(5,4)` returns 0.
        - so `ourSum(4,4)` returns `4+0 = 4`
      - Now `ourSum(3,4)` is `3+4 = 7`
    - OK, `ourSum(2,4)` is `2+7 = 9`
  - `ourSum(1,4)` returns `1+9 = 10`.

`print` and `margin` are used to report these situations nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This is because lower is different in every function call, and you add it to ourSum(...) every time to get results.

`results = lower + ourSum(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)`

This line is executed at each function call. So your function basically computes the sum of every value `lower` takes, i.e. the sum of all numbers between 1 and 4.

The return value of the 5th call is `0`.

In the 4th call, the value of lower is `4` (as you can see in the output of your function). Therefore the return value of the 4th call is `lower + ourSum(...)` = `0 + 4` = `4`.

The return value of the 3rd call is then `lower + ourSum(...)` = `3 + 4` = 7.
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Change `print(blanks, lower, upper)` to `print('A', blanks, lower, upper)` and you will see that you never return until after printing the zero value.

So all the first half printing is on the first print.  You also need to remember that the values are all local so at the point when you have finally returned 0 you add one to the local lower value of 3 and so on.